# How debug dynamic library in such situation

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake

Well, I am new to CMake.
I have the following file structure

```
    haze_removal
    |---build
    |---bin
    |    |--Test
    |    |--CMakeLists.txt
    |---lib
    |    |--libtools.so
    |---include
    |    |--tools.hpp
    |---test
    |    |--main.cpp
    |    |--CMakeLists.txt
    |---src
    |    |--tools.cpp
    |    |--CMakeLists.txt
    |---CMakeLists.txt
```

The libtools.so is builded from `../src/tools.cpp`. I build the whole project in `../build` using the following cmake command:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
make`

The Test is build from `../test/main.cpp`
I build this project successfully. But when I debug Test using `gdb ./Test`, I can't skip in the function that from libtools.so.
These are my `CMakeLists.txt` from different directories.

CMakeLists.txt under `haze_removal/`

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    project(haze_removal)

    # find needed package
    find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

    # library directory
    add_subdirectory(src)

    # test
    add_subdirectory(test)
```

CMakeLists.txt under `../src/`

```
    # generate dynamic library
    # add source file, include directories
    aux_source_directory(. TOOLS_SRC)
    include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

    # generate
    add_library(tools SHARED ${TOOLS_SRC})

    # set output directory and lib's name
    set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
    set_target_properties(tools PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "tools")

    # link library
    target_link_libraries(tools ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

CMakeLists.txt under `../test/`

```
    # add source file, include directories, link directories
    aux_source_directory(. EXE_SRC)
    include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
    link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

    # generate
    add_executable(Test ${EXE_SRC})

    # set output directory
    set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

    # link libraries
    target_link_libraries(Test ${OpenCV_LIBS} libtools.so)
```

My question is how I can debug the functions that from libtools.

Comment: I'm not sure how you load that dynamic library as I see no sources of your project. My guess is that the symbols of your dynlib are not loaded. Maybe you can tell that gdb to do so.

Comment: Sorry, It is `libtools.so` I can't skip in. I just make a mistake in the previous question, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find that why I can't step in the dynamic library even though I set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`. Because before I set the build model to Debug I used to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`. After I change the build model, I didn't delete the files in the `build` directory.

I don't know whether the above explanation is right or not, but I do solve my problem.

Thx!